# Is this notation of the set of possible compositions for a given set of functions rigorous?

Tags: notation

I have a set $F=\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\}$, where $f_i:A_i\to B_i$ and I want the notation for the set $F'$ of all possible combination of compositions between them (possibly infinite). This is what I have:

$$F'=\{f_1\circ\cdots\circ f_i\circ\cdots\circ f_n\mid \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall f'\in F^n:f_i=f'_i\}$$

Here $F^n=F\times \ldots\times F\ \text{$n$ times}$, so $f'=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\in F^n$ and $f'_i=\text{proj}_i(f')$ is the $i$-th [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(set_theory)) of $f'$.

Is this notation rigorous? Isn't there a simpler way of describing the same set?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend saying something like [the composition semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup) generated by $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\}$ (and explain this briefly in words), rather than trying to symbolically code up things with mathematical clutter that no one is going to want to try to decode in order to figure out what you really mean.